# Wxpython Break While Loop

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, wxpython

I'm creating a simple GUI, a `frame` with two buttons, Start button & Stop button using `wxpython`. When you press the Start button, the program should start printing numbers starting from 1. when you press the Stop button, the program should stop printing the numbers and print 'Done'. I'm using a while loop to continuously print the numbers. The Stop button should 'break' the while loop, however it causes the program to freeze. I know that somehow I should use threads. My question is: How to create button event as a thread?

```
import wx
import time

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.btn_start = wx.Button(self, label="Start")

        self.btn_start.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Loop)

        self.btn_stop = wx.Button(self, label="Stop")

        self.btn_stop.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Loop)

        sizer.Add(self.btn_start, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        sizer.Add(self.btn_stop, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.condition = True

    def Loop(self, event):        
        count = 0
        button = event.GetEventObject()

        while self.condition:
            labelName = button.GetLabel()
            count = count+1
            print(count)
            time.sleep(1)
            if labelName == 'Stop':
                print("Done")
                break       

class FrameOne(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="First Frame")
        panel = PanelOne(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = FrameOne()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a bool that is initially set to false

Have your start button call a thread that sets the bool to true and then starts a while loop based on this bool, inside this loop have your counter and any other logic.

Now that your counter is in its own thread the stop button can be used to set the bool to false and therefore killing the while loop, the thread will then come to an end.

here's a link explaining python threading

https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: I know how to create a thread object, but how can I call thread using a button? what should I change in the bind function, self.btn_start.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Loop)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem. Thank u 'Spriggsy'. If I want to share my solution, for other people, how can I add it here?

Comment: There should be a blue button bellow "Add Another Answer" or "Answer Your Question" select that and type in the answer. Its always good to show how you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. If there's a room for improvement, please tell me.

```
import wx
import time
import threading

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.btn_start = wx.Button(self, label="Start")

        self.btn_start.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.LoopCond)

        #self.condition

        self.btn_stop = wx.Button(self, label="Stop")

        self.btn_stop.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.LoopCond)

        sizer.Add(self.btn_start, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        sizer.Add(self.btn_stop, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def LoopCond(self, event):
        button = event.GetEventObject()
        self.labelName = button.GetLabel()
        if self.labelName == 'Start':
            self.condition = True
            threading.Thread(target= self.Loop, args=(self.condition,), daemon=True).start()
            self.btn_start.Enable(False)
        else:
            self.condition = False
            threading.Thread(target= self.Loop, args=(self.condition,), daemon=True).start()
            self.btn_start.Enable(True)
            #parent_frame = self.GetParent()
            #parent_frame.Close()


    def Loop(self, condition):        
        count = 0
        while condition:
            count = count+1
            print(count)
            time.sleep(1)            
            if self.labelName == 'Stop':
                print("Done")
                break            

class FrameOne(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="First Frame")
        panel = PanelOne(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = FrameOne()
    app.MainLoop()
```